# Update a pandas dataframe daily

Tags: python, pandas

This is somewhat of an abstract question so bear with me. Is it possible to create a pandas dataframe with some data and then append new data to it on a daily basis?

EDIT: The script below is close to what I'm looking to do. The best way I can explain my end goal would be that instead of creating a new lineup_df each day, that dataframe would already include past data and the rest of the script would add any new data. Hopefully that makes sense.

```
import requests
import csv
from random import choice
import pandas as pd

url_template = "https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashptstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom={date}&DateTo={date}&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PerMode=Totals&PlayerExperience=&PlayerOrTeam=Player&PlayerPosition=&PtMeasureType=SpeedDistance&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight="

lineup_df = pd.DataFrame()

df = pd.read_csv('NBADates.csv')
df.to_dict('series')

url_list=[url_template.format(date=date) for date in df.loc[ : ,"Date"]]

for index, url in enumerate(url_list):

    data = requests.get(url, headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0',})

    headers = data.json()['resultSets'][0]['headers']        
    stats = data.json()['resultSets'][0]['rowSet']

    stats_df = pd.DataFrame(stats, columns=headers)
    stats_df = stats_df.assign(Date2=df.loc[index, "Date2"])

    # Append to the big dataframe
    lineup_df = lineup_df.append(stats_df, ignore_index=True)

lineup_df.to_csv("DailyPlayerStatsHustle.csv")
```

Comment: Hey @Nick -- the answer to your question is yes, but this question is rather vague. There are a plethora of technologies that could set this up and without knowing more about your use case/where you want to run it, it's hard to answer! Can you add some specifics to your question?

Comment: Check my edit, hopefully that's specific enough

Answer (score 0):

You may use a file, namely a csv file (comma separed values) to store data, and use the pandas table to update and show the csv file. Though, there is a pandas format file but I haven't used it myself, or you can store it in a binary format file (faster, smaller but harder to manage). If you plan to do it automatically, you cloud compare the system's current date, against the time you want (a day) then update the file with the new data, then update the table.

Comment: That's initially what I planned on doing. Was hoping their might be a way of going about it with less steps, as I would have to write a decent amount of VBA code to prevent overlaps in the CSV file.

Comment: I can see you plan to store players stats, you may already know, but data can grow really big, and a csv file may slow things down when it reaches certain size, I'd rather use a Database like My SQL (free alternative) that is designed specially to be as fast as posible and store a large amount of data. Plus, using the SQL its easier  to perform queries. Then you could use the pandas table to show the query results.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Learning mysql is on the list but haven't gotten around to it yet.